# Signout not working rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, destroy

I've done the Michael Hartl's Tutorial and now I'm using it to build a project. For Authentication/Authorization I'm basically using the same code from the tutorial and the sample app that I built with it. In my project though the signout (destroy session) is not working. After clicking the signout link it does the redirect to the home page but it has the wrong links in the navigation and I can still access pages I shouldn't be able to (indicating that I'm still signed in) and I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
render 'new'
end

def create
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in user
  redirect_to user
else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
  render 'new'
end
end

def destroy
 sign_out
 redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

Sessions Helper

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
!current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
@current_user = user
end

def current_user
@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user?(user)
user == current_user
end

def sign_out
self.current_user = nil
cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
end
```

Header Links

```
  <header>
          <h1><%= link_to image_tag('logo.gif'), root_path %></h1>
           <div id="login-sec">
          <div class="login-row">
            <div class="col">

            <% if signed_in? %>

            <ul>
              <li><%= link_to "Signout", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
            </ul>

            <% else %>  

            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "Forgot Password", "#" %></li>
                <li class="last"><%= link_to "New user register here", signup_path %>               </li>
            </ul>

            <br /><br /><center><%= link_to image_tag('go-btn.png'), signin_path %></center>
            <% end %>

          </div>
        </header>
```

User Model (where remember token is created)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :company, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 70 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, 
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true        

private

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end       
end
```

Routes File

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/about',          to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact',        to: 'static_pages#contact'
match '/signup',         to: 'users#new'
match '/about-yourself', to: 'users#about-yourself'
match '/signin',         to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout',        to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I made users before I put in the signout actions, so I could test out the signin and signup actions. No remember token was created for these users so they were always signed in and there was no remember token to destroy

Answer (score 0):

All of the code you've presented looks alright to me. Are you sure you have the appropriate entry in your config/routes.rb, it should look something like
   match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

Comment: Just edited the post to show the Model where remember token is created and the routes folder. All of the info seems right. I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out, the issue is with users without a remember token.

If your users model has the line:

```
before_save:create_remember_token
```

Then simply looping through and resaving each entry in the database through the rails console will work:

```
User.all.each { |user| user.save(validate:false)}
```

Alternatively, rake `db:reset` and then create all new users through the site.